# "The parameter is incorrect" error when using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was using TortoiseSVN successfully but now it not working and showing the following error:

> svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svnserver.xyz
>   .com:18080/svn/branches/APPS/Applications'
>
> svn: E720087: Error running context: The parameter is incorrect.

I tried everything from my end:

1. Install different versions
2. clear auth from setting.
3. Delete auth folders
4. Add rules in firewall  (I am under group policy)
5. Delete registry info

I think this happened after I installed Macafee - which I already removed.
I am using:

1. Windows 7
2. XAMPP 3.2.1
3. Http (server doesn't support https)
4. TortoiseSVN 1.9.2, Build 26806 - 64 Bit

Note: Link is working from web browser - but not working from Tortoise UI or client. I am on client machine and doesn't have access to server.

Do you guys have any idea how to solve it? I have spent several days.
Do you also know any SVN client which is similar to TortoiseSVN in UI (in function there are many)?

Comment: Did you end up figuring out what was wrong? I'm experiencing the same issue right now.

Comment: No luck - I am thinking to use someother SVNClient. In fact other SVNClient is working.